# how to prevent a field to be serialized in a serializable (marker interface) class?

Tags: android, serialization

as the title says : How to do this ?

I googles but found nothing. One post metoined an annotation, but I guess this was jackson specific.

any help ?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the keyword `transient`. Every field marked as transient won't be serialized and hence not de-serialized. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/transient)